# Hide background element on mobile with CSS

Tags: css, border

I'm VERY new to coding.

I'd like to delete the black border (screenshot attached) on the mobile site of my website. I tried this CSS code that I found online, but had no luck.

```
@media
(max-width: 768px) {
{
    #border: 0px;
}
}
```

http://www.viragocreative.com/[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK2lP.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Add the class name inside media query to control it

Comment: Which code you have tried..please added here

Answer (score 1):

you have added `media query` and it's the proper way but you didn't select a class to style, I've checked your website and in your case it will be like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row.vc_custom_1494841069452 {
    border: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

> I used `!important` because you are using it over all your site and it's not a good practice but if you want to do what you want, just add the css above

Answer (score 0):

Add the class name or add element id and remove # before border property.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .classname {
    border: 0;
  }
  /* or */
  #elementid {
    border: 0;
  }
}
```